# Searching in Graylog2 full_message

Tags: graylog2

Is it possible to search in Graylog2 full messages using Quickfilter?

I can successfully search in short messages, but it seems like full messages can be filtered only using streams.

I need to filter old full messages and new stream is applied only to new messages. Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Graylog V2.1.2, the the field `full_message` can be searched like any other field.

You can directly search `full_message`:

```
full_message: "my full message string"
```

or search across all fields:

```
"my full message string"
```

Comment: What are the differences between `message` and `full_message` field?

Comment: @KevinWittek: Good question. Please do not [ask a new question in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129616/is-it-ok-to-ask-a-new-related-question-in-the-comments). If you want to ask something, use the "Ask question" button :-).

Answer (score 7):

Found a way to search full_message terms:

In "analytics" tab there is analytics shell where you can execute custom commands.

Example:

```
all.find(full_message="term")
```

Note from Graylog Analytics Shell instructions:

> The fields message and full_message are broken to terms. This means
>   that searches on them do not mean equals [search term] but contains
>   [search term].